# JS collapse isn't displaying my content correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to get this to work but sadly I lack the knowledge in JS. 
The content gets behind the collapsible div most of the time [image]

is anyone able to help me fix this?

This is my js file :

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + 50 + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

https://codepen.io/FGamerNL/pen/qYJOxx

Comment: I think the codepen link you shared is working correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

The `max-height` of your outer `<div class="content"></div>` is not recalculated, when you toggle one of it’s children.

Comment: could you tell me how? I've tried several things but sadly none of them worked :s

Answer (score 0):

I think you need set `maxHeight` for `parentElement` has "content" class when click to children.